# Transform a javascript array of object to an array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am looking an elegant way in ES6 to transform this array:

```
var src = [{x:1,y:'a'},{x:2,y:'b'}];
```

To this array:

```
var desc = [[1,2],["a","b"]];
```

Which contains an array of all the properties and one array for all the values.

For this, i have written this code:

```
var src = [{x:1,y:'a'},{x:2,y:'b'}];

var prop1 = [];
var prop2 = [];

src.forEach(item => {
    prop1.push(item.x)
    prop2.push(item.y);
});

var desc = [prop1, prop2];
```

It works fine but it is quite long, so I am looking for an eventual improvement and a short code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Actually I would keep it as you have it. It is very readable and you dont have to think about "what would be the output". Having everything in one line does not necessarily mean that it is better or "more clever"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You name the props order (because the order of keys in object is not guaranteed) and then map over `src` array by extracting correspondend prop value.

```js
var src = [{x:1,y:'a'},{x:2,y:'b'}]

var props = ['x', 'y'];

var result = props.map(prop => src.map(x => x[prop]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice one. However could be more cool if `props = Object.keys(src[0])` instead of hard coded values.

Comment: @MohammadUsman Not really. The order of keys is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot about order in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.reduce()`:

```js
let src = [{x: 1, y: 'a'}, {x:2, y: 'b'}];

let result = src.reduce((a, c) => (a[0].push(c.x), a[1].push(c.y), a), [[], []]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`Comma Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and then by the keys of the object and switch the outer and inner indices the target element.

```js
var src = [{ x: 1, y: 'a' }, { x: 2, y: 'b' }],
    desc = [];

src.forEach(o => Object.keys(o).forEach((k, i) => (desc[i] = desc[i] || []).push(o[k])));

console.log(desc);
```

Comment: The only possible issue is that property order is not guaranteed in an object

Comment: right, i assume, the keys have the same order, as in the given code.